# JQuery: convert var's html contents to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

I have a var that gets the HTML of a div. I want to use that var in a hidden form field so I can save the HTML to a database.

I am just having difficulty converting the HTML or the var to a string. Currently, adding the var to my input as is disrupts the code.

I have tried using `.wrap('<pre />');` in a few different ways but it doesnt help and I dont think it is right.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
var code = $('#container').html();

code = code.wrap('<pre />')

document.write('<input type="hidden" name="html" value="' + code + '">');
```

Comment: much better to use textarea to display html..able to display line breaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're better off using the helper methods over a direct `document.write` as (because it's HTML) you'll need to escape it (ensure no quotation marks are witin the code). Long story short, maybe use something like:

```
$('<input>',{
  'type':'hidden',
  'name':'html'
}) // create element
  .val(code) // use helper to insert HTML (auto-excapes)
  .appendTo('body'); // insert it where ever you need it
```

---

Further explanation: Say, for example, `code` had the following:

```
<div class="foo">bar</div>
```

By using a document write (and not escaping it) you're writing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="html" value="<div class="foo">bar</div>">
```

The `class="foo"` (and its quotes) interfere with the original hidden element's `value=""` attribute. using `.val()` avoids this because it makes sure the value is safely inserted in to the element.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery, this is probably the best way to do it...**

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function (){ 
        var code = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#container').html());
        jQuery("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="html" value="' + code + '">');
});
```